# Acknowledgement ids invalid error when used Exactly once delivery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In my spring boot application, I'm trying to use the exactly once delivery strategy with Pub/Sub. For the subscription itself, the exactly once delivery option is enabled. But periodically I see in the logs a warning:

> com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were invalid. This could be because the acknowledgement ids have expired or the acknowledgement ids were malformed.

and then followed by the info message:

> Permanent error invalid ack id message, will not resend.

The mavenBom version I use is `"com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:3.4.0"` with the following configuration:

```
   @Bean 
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
        @Qualifier("inputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
        PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate
    ) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
            new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, subscriptionName);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("inputChannel")
    public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {
       // logic for processing the message
       originalMessage.ack();
    }
```

Why is the warning displayed and what issues could it cause? Is something else missing in the configuration above, and if so - what will be the appropriate configuration?